# In TypeScript,when I use myMap to extends Map,but it‘s show Expected 0 argument

Tags: typescript

Can't the Map of js accept a parameter? Is there any expert who can teach me？

```
class myMap extends Map {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `extends Map` without the generic arguments? I'd expect at least something like `extends Map<any, any>` or `extends Map<unknown, unknown>` if not more specific.

Answer (score 4):

The type definition of Map is...

```
interface MapConstructor {
    new(): Map<any, any>;
    new<K, V>(entries?: readonly (readonly [K, V])[] | null): Map<K, V>;
    readonly prototype: Map<any, any>;
}
```

which gives 2 constructor functions...

1. Non-Generic `new` which doesn't have any parameters
2. Generic `new<K, V>` which takes 1 parameter

Both of which return(s) an interface of `Map<K, V>`. Now when we are `extending` `myMap` with a non-generic `Map`, the constructor available is parameter-less. To be able to pass a parameter, we can write the definition of `myMap` as such, unless we have any other reason not to..

```
class myMap extends Map<string, string> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
  }
}
```

where `Map<string, string>` is just an example for illustration. We will have to decide upon the actual type of `Map<K, V>` from the context of the usecase.